# Client SocketException after coming out of sleep mode (S3)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF server and client system. When the client computer enters low power sleep mode (S3) and is then woken up, any communication with the server throws a SocketException with the message "A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host <ip address of server>". Once I have restarted the client software, I can immediately connect to the server again.

My best guess is that the system has powered down the NIC when going into the sleep state and the client tries to initiate a connection to the server before the NIC reinitializes. Are there any solutions to this? I would rather not disable sleep mode on the client if I can avoid it.